# What is the average number of answers per question?

Tags: discussion, accepted-answer, data-dump, data-analysis

I'm trying to figure out two things:

1. What is the average number of answers per question on StackOverflow?
2. How many of my answers have been accepted (without having to click through several pages of answers and count them manually)?

I have only posted answers to about 300 questions on StackOverflow, but I can't find out how many of those were accepted without clicking through all of the pages and counting them manually. It may not be a big problem to do this for a user with 300 answers, but if I want to find out the same information for Jon Skeet, I will be counting for a **LOOOOONG** time!

Comment: See here http://hewgill.com/~greg/stackoverflow/stack_overflow/stats.html

Comment: @RobertHarvey I can't figure out the answers per question from those stats... :(

Comment: @Lirik, it's the fourth graph: Answer count histogram...

Comment: There's no "per person" stats on that page, but if you look through the  last couple of days of Jon Skeet's reputation pages, it's not hard to get a fair idea.  Hint: His accepted ratio is quite high.

Comment: @Benjol Ah, cool, that makes sense now! Is the y-axis the number of questions? So most questions rarely get more than 8 answers, perhaps the average is about 3 answers.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> #### 1. What is the average number of answers per question on StackOverflow?

According to [this Data Explorer query](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/s/1998/minimum-maximum-and-average-number-of-answers-per-post), the average number of answers per question is 2.35 as of October 4, 2011.

As mentioned in the comments, another great resource is [Greg Hewgill](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/893/greg-hewgill)'s [Stack Overflow Statistics](http://hewgill.com/%7Egreg/stackoverflow/stack_overflow/stats.html). On October 25, 2011, the answer count histograms look like the following.

---

[image: Answer count histogram (line)]

[image: Answer count histogram (bars)]

---

Note that the vast majority of questions have between 0 and 2 answers.

> #### 2. How many of my answers have been accepted (without having to click through several pages of answers and count them manually)?

Try entering your user ID into the following Data Explorer queries.

- [How Many of My Answers Have Been Accepted?](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/s/1996/how-many-of-my-answers-have-been-accepted)
- [Which of My Answers Have Been Accepted?](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/s/1997/which-of-my-answers-have-been-accepted)

You appear to have [99 accepted answers](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/s/1996/how-many-of-my-answers-have-been-accepted?UserId=28760) (using data up to October 4, 2011).

Comment: Woof! [Jon Skeet has 9182 answers accepted out of 17252 (as of today)](http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/s/1996/how-many-of-my-answers-have-been-accepted). That's about a 53% accept rate! I would have imagined it's much higher... :)