# View average number of answers per question in a particular time frame

Tags: support, data-explorer, statistics

[What is the average number of answers per question?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/110314) is a related question but not a duplicate since it asked for *overall* average of answers i.e. ever since the site was created. I am asking for average number of answers in a particular time frame (from date X to date Y).

Is this possible?

I looked at the Data Explorer but I am not familiar with SQL.

Comment: Must the *answers* be in a specific period, the *questions*, or both?

Comment: @Glorfindel is it possible to do both? 1. List questions posted in a particular time period 2. List questions having at least one answer posted in that time period. Thank you!

Comment: [Here](http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/803254/average-number-of-answers-per-question-time-limited) is something you could start with - 1. works if you set the answer dates to 2000-01-01 and 2019; 2. is trickier; do you want the *total* number of answers or just those posted in the specified time period?

Comment: @Glorfindel Thanks for that! 1. Could you set those two dates as default in case user does not enter any value for the first two parameters? 2. I want only those posted in the specified time period.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[This query](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/803264/average-number-of-answers-per-question-time-limited) gives you the average number of answers for questions posted from date X to date Y: on Stack Overflow, for 2017, the average is 1.47; for 2012 it's higher (1.92) but those questions have been around for a longer time.

To limit the search to question with *actual answers* within a given time frame, you can use my [first attempt](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/803254/average-number-of-answers-per-answered-question-time-limited) (the main difference between the query is using an `INNER JOIN` vs. an `OUTER JOIN`, so that questions without answers aren't selected).